# Updating Entry in db via Codeigniter and not getting the previous values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When I am trying to update data into db in codeigniter, I am getting form table values empty while I should get the previous entries so that I can Update. The update form should contain the existing values in editable format.

Here is my Controller

```
<?php

class Person extends CI_Controller {

    // num of records per page
    private $limit = 15;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();


        // $this->load->library('table','form_validation');
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules();


        $this->load->helper('url');


        $this->load->model('personModel', '', TRUE);
    }

    function index($offset = 0) {

        $uri_segment = 3;
        $offset = $this->uri->segment($uri_segment);

        // load data
        $persons = $this->personModel->get_paged_list($this->limit, $offset)->result();

        // have pagntn
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('person/index/');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->personModel->count_all();
        $config['per_page'] = $this->limit;
        $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        // generate table data
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->table->set_empty("&nbsp;");
        $this->table->set_heading('No', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Education', 'Date of Birth (dd-mm-yyyy)', 'Interest');
        $i = 0 + $offset;
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            $this->table->add_row(++$i, $person->name, strtoupper($person->gender) == 'M' ? 'Male' : 'Female',
                    // ($person->education), date('d-m-Y', strtotime($person->dob)), ($person->interest), anchor('person/view/' . $person->id, 'view', array('class' => 'view', 'onclick' => "return confirm('View Full Details?')")) . ' ' .
                    ($person->education), date('d-m-Y', strtotime($person->dob)), ($person->interest), anchor('person/view/' . $person->id, 'view', array('class' => 'view')) . ' ' .
                    anchor('person/update/' . $person->id, 'Edit', array('class' => 'update')) . ' ' .
                    anchor('person/delete/' . $person->id, 'delete', array('class' => 'delete', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure want to delete this person?')"))
            );
        }
        $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // load view
        $this->load->view('personList', $data);
    }

    function add() {

        // set validation propert/ies
        //  $this->set_fields();
        //echo"hello";
        //
          //  exit;
        // set common properties
        $data['title'] = 'Add new person';
        $data['message'] = '';
        $data['action'] = site_url('person/addPerson');
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('person/index/', 'Back to list of persons', array('class' => 'back'));

        // load view
        $this->load->view('personEdit', $data);
    }

    function addPerson() {
        // set common properties
        $data['title'] = 'Add new person';
        $data['action'] = site_url('person/addPerson');
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('person/index/', 'Back to list of persons', array('class' => 'back'));

        // set validation properties
        $this->set_fields();
        $this->set_rules();

//  
        $this->load->view('personEdit', $data);
    }

    function view($id) {
        // set common properties
        $data['title'] = 'Person Details';
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('person/index/', 'Back to list of persons', array('class' => 'back'));

        // get person details
        $data['person'] = $this->personModel->get_by_id($id)->row();

        // load view
        $this->load->view('personView', $data);
    }

    function update($id) {
        $this->set_fields();

        // prefill form values
        $person = $this->personModel->get_by_id($id)->row();
        $this->form_validation->name = $person->name;
        $_POST['gender'] = strtoupper($person->gender);
        $this->form_validation->dob = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($person->dob));
        $data = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
            'education' => $this->input->post('education'),
            'interest' => $this->input->post('interest')
        );



        // set common properties
        // load view
        $this->load->view('personEdit', $data);
    }

    function update_action() {

        $this->set_fields();

        $id = $this->input->post('emp_id');
        // prefill form values
        $person = $this->personModel->get_by_id($id)->row();
        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
            'education' => $this->input->post('education'),
            'interest' => $this->input->post('interest')
        );


        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('tbl_person', $data);


        redirect('person', 'view');

        $data['message'] = '<div class="success">update person success</div>';
        echo $data['message'];
    }

    function delete($id) {
        // delete person
        $this->personModel->delete($id);

        // redirect to person list page
        redirect('login/index/', 'refresh');
    }

    // validation fields
    function set_fields() {
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'name', 'gender','dob','education','interest', 'required');


        $fields['id'] = 'id';
        $fields['name'] = 'name';
        $fields['gender'] = 'gender';
        $fields['dob'] = 'dob';
        $fields['education'] = 'educaiton';
        $fields['interest'] = 'interest';



        //  $this->validation->set_fields('$fields');
        //echo"hellofff";
        //exit;
    }

    // validation rules
    function set_rules() {
        $rules['name'] = 'trim|required';
        $rules['gender'] = 'trim|required';
        $rules['dob'] = 'trim|required|callback_valid_date';
        $rules['education'] = 'trim|required';
        $rules['interest'] = 'trim|required';
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '* required');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('isset', '* required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
    }

    function form_validation() {
        $this->add();
    }

    // date_validation callback
    function valid_date($str) {
        if (!ereg("^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([0-9]{4})$", $str)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_date', 'date format is not valid. dd-mm-yyyy');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

How can I get those values into the fields.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `update()` for getting previous values and `update_action` for adding new values to the previous one. If that is the case,why are you using `$this->input->post` in `update()` function! Just change it like this...

```
function update($id) {
    $this->set_fields();

    // prefill form values
    $person = $this->personModel->get_by_id($id)->row();
    $this->form_validation->name = $person->name;
    $_POST['gender'] = strtoupper($person->gender);
    $this->form_validation->dob = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($person->dob));
    $data = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $person['name'], // you can also use $person->name
        'gender' => $person['gender'],
        'dob' => $person['dob'],
        'education' => $person['education'],
        'interest' => $person['interest']
    );

    $this->load->view('personEdit', $data);
}
```

Comment: Could really reduce that code a fair bit by just calling $data= $this->personModel->get_by_id($id); as long as the get_by_id returns an array the $data array would be prepopulated no?

Comment: @RickCalder Yup,but we are not sure how the op is retrieving the data in the `$data` array in his view file,right?

Answer (score 0):

You just need the set value function in your view

```
<?php echo form_input('name',set_value('name', $person->name));?>
```

This will make the default value of your to become `$person->name;` when the form is first loaded and after validation fails this value will still persist.